# Image for RibbonButton from Resourse.resx in WPF

Tags: binding, ribbon

I'm work in WPF application. For global menu  I use Ribbon. I need to add image to RibbonButton (LargeImageSource) from Resource.resx.

I add resource style to xaml file:

```cs
 <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Then I add my ImageConverter to xaml file:

```cs
<conv:ImageConverter x:Key="Conv" />
```

My C# class ImageConverter:

```cs
 public class ImageConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Bitmap)
        {
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            ((Bitmap)value).Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);

            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.StreamSource = stream;
            bitmap.EndInit();

            return bitmap; // use when you need normal image

            var conv = new FormatConvertedBitmap();
            conv.BeginInit();
            conv.Source = bitmap;
            conv.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Gray32Float;
            conv.EndInit();

            return conv; // use when you need grayed image

        }
        return value;
    }
```

But I don't now huw Binding Image to RibbunButton:

```cs
<RibbonButton KeyTip="N"
              Label="{x:Static res:Resources.New}"
              LargeImageSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource res:Resources},Path=newBtn, Converter={StaticResource Conv}}"/>
```

But this doesn't work. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I change XAML code for my RibbonButton:

```
"{Binding Source={x:Static res:Resources.newBtn}, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"
```

And change my ImageConverter:

```
 public class ImageConverter: IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)value).Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        image.StreamSource = ms;
        image.EndInit();

        return image;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```